# Two rds instance to one ec2 instance connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am trying to setup two RDS instance use by one EC2 instance. Is it possible to do so? How to connnect my EC2 to those RDS instances ? Is it done by creating security groups?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : yes. You can create many RDS database for your EC2.

long answer : Please read the AWS RDS documentation thoroughly. Example summary step:

- Create your EC2 and associate to subnet A
- In AWS RDS console , create a db subnet group R , point to subnet A
- Create your RDS instances, assign them to the db subnet group R
- get the RDS instances FQDN name
- From your EC2 , install correspondence client and connect using above given name

When you assign RDS to the DB subnet group same as the EC2 subnet, it will place the RDS to the same subnet, no special route definition required.